# Likeliest way to compute validation using MOD 7 check on the last number

Tags: algorithm, hash, modulo

I am attempting to perform number validation for a proprietary ID implementation. I was anticipating a spec document for the algorithm in detail, but this is all that they sent:

```
The IDs are 9 digits.
The check digit is a MOD 7 check on the last number.
```

I think I am to assume that "MOD 7" means to apply modulus 7 to something--I suspect that "the last number" means more than just applying mod 7 to the last digit, otherwise every valid ID would end in 0 or 7.

Meanwhile someone in a separate conversation said that it was actually "a CRC MOD 7 check on the last number" (throwing in "CRC"), but I *think* that this was a misspoken detail and that CRC is not used at all, but what do I know?

I am having difficulty finding information on some standard way of reading this specification and interpreting this for some "standard algorithm". Most of the samples I've found consist of many different varieties of algorithms, such as weighted or unweighted, etc.

Does anyone know how I am most likely to interpret this, or if I am supposed to ask for more information? If I am supposed to ask for more information, what questions should I ask?

Comment: Wow...that's horrible documentation.  Are the 9 digits split up somehow?  For example, normal credit cards are ####-####-####-####, so the "last number" would probably be the last 4 digits of the card number in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight variation on Briguy37's answer, this variation so far appears to actually be the correct answer in my case since initial tests seem to pass.

You do a MOD 7 check on the first eight digits of the 9-digit number as a single 8-digit integer, and then check if that result equals the last digit in the card number.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, this is horrible documentation, but here's the only way to read this that makes sense to me:

You do a MOD 7 check on the whole card number (all nine digits), and then check if that result equals the last digit in the card number.

Comment: Thank you! I had a couple sample valid numbers and that worked!

Comment: oh btw actually what I tested was the first 8 digits (not all 9 digits) for the first mod7 check .. so a slight variation but still you helped me thanks!

Comment: @stimpy77 Again, wow.  I don't know how they think those rules are clear enough.  Nice job on figuring that out, though :)

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for more information. Think of the consequences if you don't and it turns out the interpretation you received from the internets is wrong.